# Gradle build error after adding facebook dependency in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I am creating an android app currently using firebase and facebook. I am trying to add a facebook login button, but when I add the line `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'` I get the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

when I try to sync the gradle build. Here is what my app build.gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.notnow.barapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Facebook library use `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1` and you cannot use different support library with different version number. I resolved downgrading `compileSdkVersion` to `25` and all the support library to `25.3.1`. You can check that Facebook library is using `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1` at the following link: [Facebook Core Gradle](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook-core/build.gradle)

Hope it helps.